# Said yes to auto-upgrade changes from XCode 7 app to XCode 8, now app won't build

Tags: objective-c, linker, ios9, xcode8

I took a running app that was built under XCode7 and since I'm going to make some updates to it, did a build with XCode 8.  After the first build (it was successful), I got a series of "suggestions" that XCode 8 wanted to automatically make for the app.  Since I've never had problems doing that, I clicked OK and did another build under XCode 8.  Now my app won't link properly! (It's happening on two separate apps, both using Crashlytics and Ensembles)

[image: Link errors after doing auto-update in XCode 8]

How can I backout the changes that were automatically made to the app by XCode 8?

Comment: Looks like a problem with the "Ensembles" library you're trying to link into your app; maybe it failed to build, or the paths have changed in either the project or the default target directory between Xcode 7 and 8.  Either way, that seems like the logical first place to look.

Comment: I'm more concerned about the Crashlytics warnings; I think they  are all related.  SD

Comment: What about Source Control? Did you commit the app before you switched to Xcode 8? Then you can get back the old .xcodeproj file.

Comment: @Dirk forgot about that... please re-write your comment as the answer so I can give you the points... worked like a charm!

Comment: Also, any idea on how to find out what the changes were?  I have one of the apps that has several updates to it, and I don't really want to lose them.

Comment: Your source control system should be able to generate a diff for you before you reject the changes.  Or, if you've already rejected them, just do the update again from Xcode 7 -> 8 so you can generate a diff.

Comment: After updating the project, the project settings probably changed. Therefore, you have to double check `Library Search Paths` in your project settings. Make sure you have the right directories for the missing framework. It often means manually copy the file into your project folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using source control with your project, you can go back to the last committed state of your `.xcodeproj` file. Maybe this is not too far away from the state right before you switched to Xcode 8.